# Keeping the color scaling the same for different plots - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, scaling

I am working with Python and matplotlib. 
I am doing a continuously plot of some data I get from a spectrum analyser. So with every new step of my loop a new piece is added to my plot.

But i just realised that the color scaling doesn't remain the same. So sometimes if the data are a little different it makes a completely new scaling:

[image]

You can recognise it at the big red circle in the middle. The value of the entries for the red circle are all zeros. So normally it should have the same color with every new iteration. But as you can see, if you look closely, this isn't the case. Sometimes the red is a little bit darker.

I already set my `vmin`to -100 and my `vmax` to 0 :

```
 while True: 
  ... #some code 

  a = np.linspace( (i*np.pi/8-np.pi/16)%(np.pi*2) ,( i*np.pi/8+np.pi/16)%(np.pi*2) , 2)#Angle, circle is divided into 16 pieces
  b = np.linspace(start -scaleplot, stop,801) #points of the frequency + 200  more points to gain the inner circle
  A, B = np.meshgrid(a, longzeroarray)

  ax.contourf(a, b, B , cmap=cm.jet, vmin=-100, vmax=0)

  plt.draw()
```

I hope you have some helpful ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a fixed `levels`, for example (modified from [doc](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)):

You can't use `vmax` and `vmin` together with `levels`, as the former will override the latter.  To get round it, you can use masked array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

origin = 'lower'
#origin = 'upper'

delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10 * (Z1 - Z2)

levels = np.linspace(-3,2,50)
Vmin   = -1.
Vmax   = 1.
M = np.ma.array(Z, mask=((Z<Vmin)|(Z>Vmax)))

#levels = np.hstack(([Vmin], levels, [Vmax]))

f, (ax1, cax1, ax2, cax2) = plt.subplots(1,4,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[9,1,9,1]})
cf1 =  ax1.contourf(X, Y, M, levels=levels)
plt.colorbar(cf1, cax=cax1)
cf2 = ax2.contourf(X, Y, M*0.5, levels=levels)
plt.colorbar(cf2, cax=cax2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. I understand the `levels` part, but can explain me what `f, (ax1, cax1, ax2, cax2) = plt.subplots(1,4,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[9,1,9,1]})`  ?
And what does the option `cax` in the colorbar do ?

Comment: One more thing, do I still need `vmin` and `vmax` with `levels`

Comment: `f, (ax1, cax1, ax2, cax2) = plt.subplots(1,4,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[9,1,9,1]})` is to make 4 subplots in a row, with width ratio 9:1:9:1. `cax` specifies which axes colorbar is going to. Regarding `vmin` and `vmax`,  no they won't work with `levels`, they will override it.  Do you want the values outside the bounds to be ignored, or you want them to have the same color as the min or max values?

Comment: ok but why do i need coax and coax for the colorbars ? 

yeah i know that there are functions which color values in a specified color if they are over or under the min and max. but i don't need that.

Comment: `cax` is only needed when you want to put the colorbar in a user defined axis, rather than letting `matplotlib` automatically handles it.  On the other hand, to use `levels` with `vmax` and `vmin`, you may try `masked array`, see edit.

Comment: but why do you specific can with the help of two subplots ?
btw, it worked perfectly. Thanks.